# Почему новый элемент словаря записывается под ключ уже существующего?

Tags: python, list, словари

Пытаюсь решить задачку со словарями. Написала такой код:

```
d = {}
for line in range(int(input())):
    for word in input().split():
        for elem in word:
            if 65 <= ord(elem) <= 90:
                a = elem
                break
        word1 = word.lower()
        if word1 in d.keys():
            d[word1] += [a]
        else:
            d[word1] = [a]
```

Не могу понять, почему все последующие элементы записываются под ключом первого.
Входные данные:
4
cAnnot
cannOt
fOund
pAge

чтобы понять о чем речь:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
d = {}
for line in range(int(input())):
    for word in input().split():
        a = None
        for elem in word:
            if 65 <= ord(elem) <= 90:
                a = elem
                break
        word1 = word.lower()
        if word1 in d.keys():
            d[word1] += [a]
        else:
            d[word1] = [a]

print(d)
```

Результат

> {'cannot': ['A', 'O'], 'found': ['O'], 'page': ['A']}

И тут все ключи разделены как и ожидалось

Возможно вы выбрали не совсем удачный визуализатор словаря